# Transact SQL - which Join to Use

Tags: sql-server

I have two simple SELECT statements:
The first shows a list of Features.

```
SELECT * FROM Features

id  name
--  ----
1   24 Hour Access
2   24 hour CCTV monitoring
3   Airport location
4   Break-Out Areas
5   Business Lounge
6   Business park location
snip..
```

and the second statement shows a list of feature information that has changed

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    #SmartFeaturesToUpdate new_features
ORDER BY 
    new_features.centre_translation_id,
    new_features.feature_id,
    new_features.feature_selected   

feature_id  centre_translation_id feature_selected
----------  --------------------- ----------------
1           1                 1
2           1                 1
5           1                 1
10          1                 1
11          1                 1
snip..
```

What I want to see is all of the features by centre translation.
Combining the tables gives me:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    #SmartFeaturesToUpdate new_features
    LEFT JOIN Feature feature ON feature.id = new_features.feature_id
ORDER BY 
    new_features.centre_translation_id,
    new_features.feature_id,
    new_features.feature_selected

feature_id  centre_translation_id feature_selected id name
----------  --------------------- ---------------- -- ----
1           1                 1                1  24 Hour Access
2           1                 1                2  24 hour CCTV monitoring
5           1                 1                5  Business Lounge
10          1                 1                10 Double Glazing
11          1                 1                11 Elevator
snip..
```

The result above is missing feature id's 3 and 4, because they are not in the second list.
but the result I need is:

```
feature_id  centre_translation_id feature_selected id name
----------  --------------------- ---------------- -- ----
1           1                 1                1  24 Hour Access
2           1                 1                2  24 hour CCTV monitoring
3           1                 1                3  Airport Location
4           1                 1                4  Break-Out Area
5           1                 1                5  Business Lounge
snip..
```

How should I modify the third SELECT statement to acheive this and combine the results from both the features and feature information list?

Comment: Could you describe in words which is the difference and what you want to achieve? The examples are great, but a few words migth help.

Comment: Where are you getting values for the columns centre_translation_id and feature_selected for "Break-Out Area"?

Comment: Updated, does that make more sense?

Comment: I still can't see in your source data where the centre_translation_id is set to 1 for "Break-Out Area". Am I missing something?

Comment: You may be hitting the crux of the issue. I want every feature to be listed for every centre_translation_id.  feature_selected can be null after the join. centre_translation_id is currently only defined in #SmartFeaturesToUpdate

Comment: @NiceYellowEgg As openshac said, where is this query supposed to get `Airport Location` and `Break-Out Area` information from? is there another table maybe?

Comment: From the Features table, first one in the example?

Comment: But the Features table does not contain a column called centre_translation_id

Comment: Okay, I think your questions and my confusion is alluding to the fact that I need another table. One that comprises Features cross-joined with Centre_translation_ids.  Then I can left join to that and fill in the gaps.  I'll update with an answer presently

Comment: Your questions helped answer my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments alluded, I needed another table which linked Features to centre_translation_ids

First get all of the feature / centre_translation varients

```
SELECT 
    [centre_translation_id] = centre_translation.id,
    feature.id,
    feature.name
    INTO #AllTheFeatures
FROM
    CentreTranslation centre_translation 
    CROSS JOIN Feature feature  
ORDER BY 
    centre_translation.id,
    feature.id
```

Now we can simply perform the LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT
    all_features.centre_translation_id,
    all_features.id,
    all_features.name,
    smart_features.feature_selected 
FROM
    #AllTheFeatures all_features
    LEFT JOIN #SmartFeaturesToUpdate smart_features ON  smart_features.centre_translation_id = all_features.centre_translation_id AND
                                                        smart_features.feature_id = all_features.id
ORDER BY 
    all_features.centre_translation_id,
    all_features.id
```

This gives the results:

```
centre_translation_id id name                    feature_selected
--------------------- -- ----                    ----------------
1                     1  24 Hour Access          1
1                     2  24 hour CCTV monitoring 1
1                     3  Airport location        NULL
1                     4  Break-Out Areas         NULL
1                     5  Business Lounge         1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put it in one query?

```
SELECT 
    centre_translation.id AS centre_translation_id,
    feature.id,
    feature.name,
    smart_features.feature_selected 
FROM
    CentreTranslation centre_translation 
CROSS JOIN Feature feature  
LEFT JOIN #SmartFeaturesToUpdate smart_features
    ON smart_features.centre_translation_id = all_features.centre_translation_id
    AND smart_features.feature_id = all_features.id
ORDER BY 
    centre_translation.centre_translation_id,
    feature.id
```